# "Were"vs "was" in the sentence?

Tags: verbs, subjects

> Neither he nor his friends **were/was** present at the party?

Which would come here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1256/252) for ["Neither Michael nor Albert is correct" or "Neither Michael nor Albert are correct"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/neither-michael-nor-albert-is-correct-or-neither-michael-nor-albert-are-corre), in that case you should use *were* because "his friends," which is closer to the verb, is plural.
You should use *were* even if the sentence started with "neither her friends nor his friends."

Clearly, if the sentence contained "one of his friends" instead of "his friends," you should have used *was* ("neither he nor one of his friends was").

Answer (score 2):

You should use "were" in this type of sentence.

Side notes:

-spelling error: should be "Neither"

-change "present in the party" to "present at the party"

Answer (score 0):

The conventional rule is that when you have a construction like "A or B" or "A nor B" followed by a verb, the number of the verb should match the LAST thing in the list.

> Either Bob or the Baxter twins are ...
>
> Either the Baxter twins or Bob is ...
>
> Neither Bob nor the Baxter twins are ...
>
> Neither the Baxter twins nor Bob is ...

When there's an "and", it should always be followed by a plural, because we now have at least two things.

> Both the Baxter twins and Bob are ...